# What did Victor and Marcelo pressure Passos into in Max Payne 3?

Tags: max-payne-3

in Chapter XII: The Great American Savior of the Poor, the following conversation takes place:

> Max Payne: What the fuck are you doing here?
>
> Raul Passos: I came back.
>
> I can see that, but why?
>
> To save you.
>
> Oh yeah, real hero.
>
> Listen…
>
> No, "Come with me, Max… to Brazil.
>
> It'd be a chance to play the fall guy in a plot that my boss's brother is hatching to profit from the selling of human organs. Yeah, it'll be perfect for ya."
>
> Passos: "What are you talking about? I don't know nothing about human organs, man. **Victor and Marcelo were trying to teach Rodrigo a lesson, get him to loosen the purse strings on the family money. They pressured me into doing it.**"

I know Passos is no saint, but what exactly did he mean? From what Da Silva said in the previous chapter it is clear that he didn't know about the organ harvesting business, but what exactly did he mean about "teaching Rodrigo a lesson"? Did they have to do something with Fabiana's kidnapping? If not, if the source of money was the smuggling/laundering scheme in Panama, how was this supposed to teach Rodrigo a lesson? I don't think Rodrigo cared about Daphne's ship being used to smuggle money to Panama. What he certainly cared about was his wife being kidnapped.

Even if that thing they did to teach Rodrigo a lesson really was kidnapping of his wife, how would that help them, financially? Did they persuade Serrano to do the job and then what? Serrano would get the money and share with them? I don't think so, Serrano was a simple man that tried to get by by any means possible, murdering, stealing. I don't think he would stick to this kind of deal.

If Marcelo was in on this kidnapping plot (not sure about this, Da Silva said Marcelo is an idiot who didn't know what was going on), why would he take even more money to Serrano after the deal failed for the first time?

Moreover, Victor knew about everything, he was in cahoots with Becker, who was in charge of the UFE. So I'm pretty sure the moment Marcelo and Giovanna would mention their names to the UFE cops or Bechmeyer (both knew Brancos), they would know who they are...why would they hand them over to the mercenary Milo Rego? Or did Becker really think "oh well, I'm sure Victor wouldn't mind me for killing his brother and his other brother's sister in law".

There's a lot of things that don't make sense to me in Max Payne 3 (even after playing it several times over), it's either that I am not capable to understand the plot as it was written, or there are some plotholes, or some very implicit things that were left unexplained/up to the player's imagination.

Can anyone explain to me these weak spots please?

Comment: If u see this remember cursing *should be kept* if it is part of a quote or other essential information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALLO,

Kind of late reply but essentially they set up an entire plot where eventually Bachmeyer (Becker's right hand) was going to assassinate Rodrigo and pin it on Max.
That's why Victor is so surprised to hear his phone call after the attack on Fabricas Branco AND thats why he's seen on the news after the attack leaving the compound. Everything that happens before is kind of set up conveniently for Victor.

Passos was a loyal but uninformed bodyguard who knew nothing more than needed. He comes off as naive because they don't tell him, he's just extra muscle for the under the table work.

Also the whole point is that victor DOESN'T care about his family,  Marcelo, Rodrigo, Giovanna. He's just profiting from the organ harvesting scandal and probably considers them collateral. Remember he's incredibly cunning and if the other Brancos tipped the UFE off it wouldn't make a difference because they were on Victor's side.

I don't think he was involved with the Commando Sombra but he definitely was with the Cracha Preto. He knew about the money at the stadium and tipped them off. That's why the cops (UFE) never came because he told them they were there. Victor probably didn't orchestrate Fabiana's kidnapping but definitely saw it as an opportunity to get rich off Rodrigo.

But yes a lot of stuff is more or less left up to the player's imagination. Ostensibly as part of the "dumb gringo" narrative.

Comment: Nice answer! I fully agree with the dumb gringo narrative, I definitely had to go back to that game several times over to kinda comprehend the details and I had to look up some translated Portuguese to get more context (even though in most cases it's just background noise, expletives and nothing interesting in particular). It is a very fast-paced game and you're right, a lot of stuff is left up to player's imagination :)